# Can an instance of a struct or a class be considered as a variable?

Tags: c++, variables

I've read:

- A variable is a name of memory location.
- In C++, a variable is actually just a bit of memory that has been reserved for the program’s use.
  (https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/variables)
- Variable names are identifiers. Identifiers are labels used for various things in C++, including functions, classes, and namespaces as well as variables.

(meaning a variable name is just a case of identifiers)

In standard C++ terminology, Can we consider the name of an instance of a struct or a class as a variable? or Should we only call it "an identifier"?

I know it's definitely a noob question but I really couldn't answer the question myself even if I've tried to read the definition of a variable from several sources. Please help.

Comment: The name of a `class`, or a `struct`, or a primitive (like `int` or `double`), or an `enum`, or a `union` (and I'm probably missing a few) is a **type** name.

Comment: A variable is a named object with a type and a value.   A type (including a `struct` or `class` type) is not an object, and it does not have a value, so it cannot be a variable.   The purpose of identifiers is to (well) identify things - be they type names, variable names, function names, etc.

Comment: @Peter , what about an instance of a class or a struct, can we consider them as a variable? :)

Comment: Certainly.  The title of your question says it all.  Answer: yes.

Comment: I think the use is a bit fuzzy: Name or object? My gut feeling is it's a named object (which the other Peter said). I'll try to find a quote from the standard.

Comment: @Crackie   An instance of a class or struct is an object, by definition.   A variable is a named object.   So .....

Comment: @Peter , so a named object or the name of that object can be considered as a varaible! :)

Comment: @Peter , and the object we refer here, could be either object of a class or primitive type?

Comment: It's the object itself that would be considered the variable.    One of the properties of a variable (if it has one) is its name.    And, yes, an object's type can be of "primitive" type, or a class type (which is an aggregate containing zero or more objects - so an instance of a class with no data members is still an object).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++ standard defines a *variable* as such (from [[basic.pre]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.pre)):

> A *variable* is introduced by the declaration of a reference other than a non-static data member or of an object. The variable's name, if any, denotes the reference or object.

So a variable is either:

1. A reference
2. An object

That means that a type name is not a variable, but an object is (be it of a class type or a primitive type).

Comment: I am just pondering over the same sentences. "Introduced by", in my book, does not mean "is", does it?? And surely you cannot arrive at an (exclusive) "either or".

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I think it is there because the variable doesn't actually have to exist at all.  Consider a reference, it is allowed to not even exist, but it still referred to as a variable.

Answer (score 9):

Tl;dr: A variable is *usually* a named object, or a reference to an object. There are variables which do not have a name and there are those which do not have an associated object, but those are exceptions.

---

The current standard says in 6.1:

> A variable is **introduced** by the declaration of a reference [...] or of an object.

The standard is careful not to say "created" because the point of creation at run time will be different than this "introduction", especially for references. The *name* in the static code is available after the declaration; the *object* is available at some time during the run time. In the case of a reference, the object may actually be gone but the variable may still be in scope (for example when you return a reference to a local variable from a function).

We see:

- A variable may name an object: 
  `int i;`
- A variable may be a reference:
  `int i; int &ri{i};`
- Since there are dangling references, there are variables without objects:
  `int &f(){int i; return i;} int &r = f();`

It continues

> The variable’s name, if any, denotes the reference or object.

- OK: I suppose this constitutes a variable without name:
  `int &f(int /*unused*/) {}`

But not all unnamed objects are variables:
`int *p = new int{};`

`p` is, of course, a variable; the `int` it points to is not, even though it is an object.

Of course there are, if you are a friend of oxymorons, constant variables. There are also names which are not variables, for example labels.

---

You are asking actually two questions. The title is "Can *an instance* of a struct or a class be considered as a variable?" The answer is that an instance in itself is not a variable; it is just an object. You can create one with `new` as with the `int` in the example above. That would be an instance but not a variable (if you assign the address to a pointer, the pointer would a variable containing an address).

In the question body you ask something different: "Can we consider *the name of an instance* of a struct or a class as a variable?" I would say that is correct: A variable is (normally) a named object. By the way, whether it's a struct or a built-in type is unimportant here.